# Android Video doesn't start on samsung s3

Tags: android, video

So i have a problem with a videos that are displayed in a activity. 
So every thing worked fine on my samsung s4. so i thought everything is fine. 
But my friend noticed on his samsung s3 mini that the video is not playing. 
The resolution of the video is 1280 720 and the format is H.264 form mp4. i really don't know what to do if somebody could help me that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Probably s3 does not support your video format. You can check if your format is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html
If not, then it does not have to be supported by a manufacturer.